# Basic function call on init failing

Tags: plugins, php, actions, init

I've been banging my head against this for a while. I have this very straight-forward code in my plugin:

```
add_action('init', 'register_shortcodes');

$shortcodeRegistrationRan = False;

function register_shortcodes() {
    global $shortcodeRegistrationRan;
    $shortcodeRegistrationRan = True;
    echo "Ran = True";

    add_shortcode( 'accountability', array($hfMain, 'processAccountabilityShortcode') );
}
```

The problem is `$shortcodeRegistrationRan` never gets set to `True`, nor does "Ran = True" appear anywhere on the page. What am I missing?

I'm using [SimpleTest for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simpletest-for-wordpress/) to check the status of my run flag. I have plenty of other passing tests, so the test suite is running fine. My test checks this way:

```
public function testShortcodeRegistrationRan() {
    global $shortcodeRegistrationRan;
    $this->assertEqual($shortcodeRegistrationRan, True);
}
```

At the beginning of the test suite:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../[PLUGIN NAME].php');
```

**EDIT:** Per @s_ha_dum's advice, I added a new test using the [`shortcode_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_exists) function:

```
public function testShortcodeRegistration() {
    $this->assertEqual(shortcode_exists('accountability'), True);
}
```

Unfortunately, it, too, does not pass.

**EDIT:** Here is the full context:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Nathan's Awesome Widget
Plugin URI: http://NathanArthur.com/
Description: This plugin does awesome things
Author: Nathan Arthur
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://NathanArthur.com/
*/

/*global $wp_version;

if ( !version_compare($wp_version,"3.0",">=") ) {
    die("You need at least version 3.0 of Wordpress to use the copyright plugin");
}*/

function my_plugin_activate() {
    error_log("my plugin activated");
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__,"my_plugin_activate");



if (!class_exists("HfAccountability")) {
    class HfAccountability {
        private $currentUser;
        function HfAccountability() { //constructor
            $this->currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
        }
        function getCurrentUserLogin() {
            return $this->currentUser->user_login;
        }
        function processAccountabilityShortcode( $atts ) {
            #$to = '[MY EMAIL ADDRESS]';
            #$subject = 'Testing Mandrill integration';
            #$message = "Yup, that's all we're doing";
            #wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
            return 'We tried.';
        }
    }
}

if (class_exists("HfAccountability")) {
    $hfMain = new HfAccountability();
}

//Actions and Filters
/* if (isset($hfMain)) {
    //Actions
    add_action('init', 'register_shortcodes'); //PROBLEMATIC LINE

    //Filters

    $actionsRan = True;
} */

add_action('init', 'register_shortcodes');

$shortcodeRegistrationRan = False;

function register_shortcodes() {
    global $shortcodeRegistrationRan;
    $shortcodeRegistrationRan = True;
    echo "Ran = True";

    add_shortcode( 'accountability', array($hfMain, 'processAccountabilityShortcode') );
}
```

Comment: The question is where do you access this variable? A variable in functions.php isn't accessible anywhere else. This is a matter of scope.

Comment: Yes, I realized this after I posted the question — see the edited question for how I attempted to address this. Unfortunately, my attempt didn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you try printing $shortcodeRegistrationRan in testShortcodeRegistrationRan() to see if the problem is the value not being there or something further on in your testing tool?

Comment: I did, but the code has changed enough that it'd be worth trying again. I'll do that right now.

Comment: @kraftner: Just tried a simple `echo` (see edit). Still no luck.

Comment: I meant echo $shortcodeRegistrationRan in testShortcodeRegistrationRan()

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I can do that.

Comment: @kraftner: I added the echo to the test as you suggested. Nothing showed up on my page. I'm not quite sure what to make of that since I know the tests are running: `Fail: [SITE URL]/wp-content/plugins/hf-accountability/php/tests.php -> UnitWpSimpleTest -> testShortcodeRegistrationRan -> Equal expectation fails as [Boolean: false] does not match [Boolean: true] at [[SITE URL]/wp-content/plugins/hf-accountability/php/tests.php line 50]`

Comment: I also tried deactivating all other plugins. Still a no-go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel very un-smart. My problem was two-fold:

1. First, my plugin had somehow become deactivated.
2. Second, it turned out that I needed to give the `add_shortcode` function the name of the class rather than an instance of that class. It'd be great if someone could explain why this is. [This page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcodes-from-a-class) indicated that either way would work.

So, it's finally all working and my tests are passing.

Comment: It **is** possible to register class functions in object context. In this/your case, however, you first have to _globalize_ your variable/object. Just put `global $hfMain;` in your `register_shortcodes` function and all should work fine.

Comment: Oh, right! That makes sense. I can see right now I need to be a lot more careful with scope. lol

Answer (score 2):

I am going to suggest that what you are doing is overly complex, at least insofar as I understand you.

You can determine whether your shortcode has been registered using the Core function [`shortcode_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_exists), which returns a `boolean`. As far as I can tell, using that should provide completely equivalent functionality to your code above.

Comment: Wow, that is a great function! Thank you! I added a test that uses this function, but unfortunately it does not pass.

Comment: Then there is probably something contextual happening that isn't clear from your question.

Comment: I guess I can add the context.

Comment: Just edited to include the surrounding code.